# Uploading file to website with android - site cant be reached

Tags: python, android, django

I am trying to upload a file in a website using the django framework. When i use my laptop i have no problem at all, but when trying to upload the exact same file with my android device i get 'This site cant be reached'
**The problem happens when i click the submit button. I can normally access the main.html with my android device and can even access the get_post/ url without POST if i dont click the button. But when it is clicked i get 'This site cant be reached'**

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from .Uploaded_files import C_Convert as conv
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError



def main_view(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html')

def get_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(1)
        try:
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Error</h1>')
        default_storage.save('CSD_Project/Uploaded_files/'+uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        result = conv.convert(uploaded_file.name)
        return HttpResponse('<h1>%s</h1>'%result)

    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>Error</h1>')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import get_file,main_view
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', main_view),
path('get_file/', get_file) ]
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style = "background-color: darkslategrey">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HY100 Tests</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <form action="get_file/" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
       {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button style="color: white; background-color: #222222; padding: 15px 32px; font-size: 15px;" class="button">Submit file</button>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with Django at all, double-check your Android device. Is the web app deployed locally? Then you have to make sure that your device is in the same network.

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe now it is more clear. The web app is deployed locally AND i can access the main url (main_view) but the problem happens when i click the button. I can even access the get_file/ url without post and that gets me to the return HttpResponse('<h1>Error</h1>') . Something must be wrong with submiting the uploaded file.

Comment: There arent actually any errors considering python script,besides showing my get_post link with the above error. It doesnt even get inside the function get_file, so the print(1) command is not executed. Thats what i dont understand.

Comment: in form  I would use absolute path `/get_file` instead of relative `get_file/`

Comment: @furas tried it, the problem persists

Comment: you should see some information in console/terminal/cmd.exe when you run it in console. Maybe there is information about problem. Maybe is shows what url it tries to get. Also running in debug mode you should see more info on page.